# Location of solutions in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis

Please help with this practice prelim problem.

> Try to show that the equation 
>   $$
> (z-1)^ne^z = a
> $$
>   where $n$ is a positive integer and $|a|<1$ has exactly $n$ solutions in the right half plane.

I have tried to take logs of both sides and then apply Rouche's theorem, but I haven't been able to finish the problem this way.

Comment: *To get the best possible answers, you should explain what your thoughts on the problem are so far*. That way, people won't tell you things you already know, and they can write answers at an appropriate level; also, people tend to be more willing to help you if you show that you've tried the problem yourself.

Comment: I have tried to take logs of both sides and then apply Rouche's theorem.

Comment: @EagerStudent Taking logs of complex numbers is a very risky business since logarithms are multi-values finctions. For example: $\ln z = \ln|z| + i \operatorname{arg} z$. For example, $\ln 1 \in \{ 2\pi i n : n \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define

$$f(z):=(z-1)^n\;,\;\;g(z):=-\frac{a}{e^z}$$

Both are holomorphic functions, and on the boundary of $\,\{z\in\Bbb C\;;\;|z-1|\le 1\}\,$ we have

$$|g(z)|=\frac{|a|}{e^{\text{Re}(z)}}\le|a|<1=|z-1|=|f(z)|\implies$$

By Rouche's theorem, $\,f(z)\;\;\text{and}\;\;\;f(z)+g(z)\;$ have the same number of zeros inside the domain  $\,|z-1|<1\,$ ...